# Dynamic addition of elements in a tree in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects in angularjs

```
var list = [{id: 'foo' , value:'bar1'},
 {id: 'foo1' , value:'bar1'}];
```

I want to add a child object for the first `id` that equals 'foo'

Formatted JSON Data:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":'foo',
      "value":'bar1',
      "children":{  
         id:'foo',
         value:'baar'
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":'foo1',
      "value":'bar1'
   }
];
```

I have tried

```
var tempList = {id:'foo', value:'baar'};

if(list.id =='foo' )
list.id.children = tempList ;
```

But its not inserting the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do it with `foreach` if you are matching the ids of parent list and child list then use this -

```
angular.forEach(list , function(value, key){
      if(value.id== tempList.id)
         obj.children = tempList ;
   });
```

hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

use `map` function to add property to object

```js
var list = [
  {id: 'foo' , value:'bar1'},
  {id: 'foo1' , value:'bar1'}
]; 
 

var tempList = {id:'foo', value:'baar'};

list = list.map(function(obj){
  if(obj.id =='foo'){
    obj.children = tempList ;
  }
  
  return obj
})
console.log(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this but this will overwrite the id value:

```
 var list = [{id: 'foo' ,
         value:'bar1'},
        {id: 'foo1' ,
         value:'bar1'}];

 var tempList = {id:'foo', value:'baar'};

 list = list.map(function(obj){

 if(obj.id == 'foo')
 {
   delete obj.id;
   obj.id = {}; 
   obj.id.children = tempList ;
 }

 return obj;
});

console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :** `if(list.id == 'foo')` is invalid syntax as `list` is an array of objects.

So, You can access the id like this `list[index].id` instead of `list.id`.

So, to iterate the list array you can use JavaScript [**for...in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

**DEMO**

```js
var list = [{id: 'foo' , value:'bar1'},
 {id: 'foo1' , value:'bar1'}];
 
 for (var i in list) {
   if(list[i].id =='foo') {
     list[i].children = {  
         id:'foo',
         value:'baar'
      };
   }
 };
 
 console.log(list);
```